# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field webview of type I in class

Tags: android, webview, aar

i am doing payment gateway integration in my app. For that there is a aar file given by Gateway for android. if i have included in separate project like new project,it is working but when i have included in main project and run it, it is giving below error.

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field webview of type I in class Lcom/test/pg/secure/pgsdkv4/R$id; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.test.pg.secure.pgsdkv4.R$id' appears in /data/app/com.evalai.rmcnet-ZOpmFHEO15YPjyZmCMGQiw==/base.apk!classes5.dex)

.

In my project i have used firebase also.is that problem?